# convert whole folder of images to 777 permissions?

Tags: php, apache, ftp

I took an opportunity to batch optimise a folder of images from my site, of course i forgot the new images would not have the permissions `777`.

> Given the wiki-type nature of my site
>   i need users to be able upload/replace
>   the images!

is there anyway i can change the permissions of the whole folder's images either with a php script or ftp program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In filezilla: Select all -> Right click -> File permissions (at the bottom)

with php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: nothing like right clicking on something for easiness! thanks  Arnar

Answer (score 1):

Use `chmod()` function, documentation you can find at http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        chmod($file, 0777);
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: isn't this just for a single file?

Comment: @Haroldo - it is. If, for some reason, you can't use the command-line program, you could loop over all files in the directory and call chmod(), passing each filename

Comment: @bobby ah ok, this is what i though just hoped there might be a neater solution

Comment: Probably want to check for "." and ".."

Answer (score 0):

How about `chmod 777 *`?

If you don't have access to the command-line, you should be able to use one of the [Program execution functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) such as [exec](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: wow that looks a bit hardcore, i thought maybe there'd be a recursive php chmod flag or something?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single PHP function to do this - chmod() doesn't seem to take a wildcard. You could call chmod() in a loop over all filenames, though.